# powershell format list output to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, transpose

How can i convert the output of a format list object from powershell to a dataframe where the columns are a merged conglomerate of the first column and the values correspond to the appropriate set of info?

data:

```
a    : data
b    : data2
c    : data3

a    : data10
b    : data20
c    : data30
```

expected output:

```
a         b           c
data      data2       data3
data10    data20      data30
```

I have tried to Transponse my df but it doesnt merge the a,b,c.

Any help would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a new para key by using `cumcount`, then we `pivot`

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('v').cumcount()).pivot('key','v','s')
Out[242]: 
v         a       b       c
key                        
0      data   data2   data3
1    data10  data20  data30
```

Data input

```
df
Out[243]: 
   v       s
0  a    data
1  b   data2
2  c   data3
3  a  data10
4  b  data20
5  c  data30
```